# WSO2 API Manager Connection Error , "Error occurred while sending the HEAD request to the given endpoint url"

Tags: java, rest, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-appm

I'm trying to configure the WSO2 API Manager. (version - v4.0.0)
When I try to create REST API and point to the endpoints I"m getting a  **Connection error**  message for the given endpoints. I have hosted the API Manager and the back end services on the same server(backend services are running on the tomcat application on the same server in port 8080)

API Manager Log produces the following message :

```
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.v1.impl.ApisApiServiceImpl} - Error occurred while sending the HEAD request to the given endpoint url: org.apache.commons.httpclient.ConnectTimeoutException: The host did not accept the connection within timeout of 4000 ms
```

would really like to what has caused the issue.

P.S: I can access the backend services directly without any connection issues using a REST client.[image]

Comment: What's the backend url provided? If these are running on the same server you can provide localhost:8080 as the backend url. I guess you have given the externally exposed url to the APIM and it cannot connect.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to answer the question without knowing the exact details of your deployment and the backend. But let me try. Here is what I think is happening. As you can clearly see, the error is a connection timeout `The host did not accept the connection within timeout of 4000 ms`.

Let me explain what happens when you click on the Check `Endpoint Status` button. When you click on the `Check Endpoint Status` button, the Browser is not directly sending a request to the Backend to validate it. The Backend URL will be passed to the APIM Server, and the Server will perform the validation by sending an HTTP `HEAD` request to the BE service.

So there can be two causes. First may be your backend doesn't know how to handle a HEAD request which is preventing it from accepting the request. But given the error indicated it's a network issue, I doubt it even reached the BE.

The second one is, that your Backend is not accessible from the place API Manager is running. If you are running API Manager on `Server A` and trying to access API Manager via browser from `Server B`(Local Machine). Although you can access the BE from `Server B` may be from `Server A` it's not accessible. When I say BE is not accessible from `API Manager` server, it means it's not accessible with the same URL that was used in API Manager. It doesn't really matter if it runs in the same Server if you are using a different DNS other than localhost to access it. So go to the server API Manager is running and send a request using the same URL that was used in API Manager and see whether it's accessible from there.

Comment: As i mentioned in the question i have hosted backend services and API Manager on the same server. I can directly access the backend services via REST client (POSTMAN) or Curl Request. Issue is i cannot connect to backend services through the API Manager, getting a connection error. Server instance is a azure vm.

Comment: As I previously mentioned BE runs on 8080 port on the API Manager hosted server. Yes I’m aware it not connects to BE directly when I click check connection status button. It’s not hitting to the backend services when I click check connection button. I feel like something blocking the connection when I request it through the API Manager.

Comment: @ncgamer99 As I mentioned you need to login to the API Manager Azure VM and do a `curl` to the BE server using the same URL you have provided in the API. If that works, everything should work. I'm assuming you have given a external URL in the API and this URL is not accessible from the VM. Also, as @Pubci mentioned,  you can use `localhost:8080` as the backend URL if it's in the same server.

Comment: Backend services and the API Manager runs on the same server. It just a one instance. I can curl to the backend services from my local machine. My issue is I can’t connect to BE through API Manager.It’s not a external URL.

Comment: @ncgamer99 What is the Backend URL added in the API Manager? Just tell us, is it something other than `localhost:8080`?

Comment: I was able to sort the above issue by starting to build it from scratch. yes, I have given localhost and private IP  and now it works for both. (I can see it's getting hit to my BE from the log ). Now  I'm getting another error code when I test it in the try-out section or the dev portal. error code as follows code: 101508.                                         {
    "code": "101508",
    "type": "Status report",
    "message": "Runtime Error",
    "description": "Error connecting to the back end"
}

Comment: @ncgamer99 Feel free to create a new SO Question for the new issue with the relevant details.

Answer (score 0):

First try doing a curl request by login into the server where APIM is running (not from your local machine). Maybe due to some firewall rules within the server, the hostname given in the URL may not be accessible. Also, try sending a `HEAD` request as well. You might be able to get some idea why this is happening